# /usr/bin/Rscript: Argument list too long

Tags: r, bash, rscript

Using rscript inside a bash script

I am passing the content of text files has arguments. to rscript

`"$SCRIPTS/myscript.R" "$filecontent"`

I get the following when file have +- over 4000 row

`/usr/bin/Rscript: Argument list too long`

Any way I can increase the length of accepted argument so I can pass large files?

Comment: Instead of passing the the file contents, why not pass the file name so the script can open it itself? Or possibly stream the contents to the script via stdin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What @MrFlick said is correct - you should change the way the arguments are passed to your script.  However, if you still want to try to do it your way, then I recommend reading the following article:

[**"Argument list too long": Beyond Arguments and Limitations**](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6060?page=0,0)

> The "Argument list too long" error, which occurs anytime a user feeds
>   too many arguments to a single command, leaves the user to fend for
>   oneself, since all regular system commands (ls *, cp *, rm *, etc...)
>   are subject to the same limitation. This article will focus on
>   identifying four different workaround solutions to this problem, each
>   method using varying degrees of complexity to solve different
>   potential problems.

Also, this Unix&Linux thread can help:

[**“Argument list too long”: How do I deal with it, without changing my command?**](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/45583/argument-list-too-long-how-do-i-deal-with-it-without-changing-my-command)

Comment: Tried the option in  _How do I deal with it, without changing my command?_ 
`setting ulimit -s unlimited`
still got the "Argument list too long" error
turned to an other solution involving not using arguments. Has suggested.